# Reading http input request from the browser to a socket - never closes the input stream

Tags: sockets, http, socket.io, inputstream

I'm reading from the socket's input stream and never receives the end of stream signal. I'm reading an HTTP request made by a browser. See example below.

**How do I know that there's nothing more to be read?**

```
POST /hello?a=b HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:4444
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Origin: null
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
```

Comment: The server has to read the client's headers first, then analyze them to discover how the request body is being sent and how it is terminated, then the server can read the body as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is using HTTP 1.1, and has a (redundant in 1.1) `Connection: keep-alive` header.  If the response does not contain a `Connection: close` header, the server will not close the connection after sending the response.  This is how HTTP keep-alive is designed to work (see [RFC 2616 Section 8 "Connections"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8)).  The client must look at the response headers to determine how to read the response body and determine when the response has ended (see [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4)), and then decide whether to close the connection or not.  Do not rely on an end-of-stream signal, that is not how HTTP works.

**Update**: I just realized that you are writing the server, not the client.  [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) applies to reading requests as well.  The client will send headers first, which are terminated by a `"\r\n\r\n"` sequence, and then the headers describe how the request body is formatted and terminated, which allows the server to read the body until the end of the request is reached.

Comment: `\r\n\r\n` sounds right to me. There is an option to close just the output of the socket - see java's `socket.shutdownOutput()`. If the browser doesn't have anything to send anymore, why doesn't it just closes the output? This would have made the reading much easier on the server side.

Comment: I guess you'd still need to know when the header finishes if you have content in the body...

Answer (score 0):

The only "end-of-stream" indicator TCP can deliver is closing the connection.

If the connection remains open there is no possiblilty for TCP to tell you "That's it!", as TCP is stream oriented not message oriented.

So, whether there is more  to read or not can only be decided on application (protocol) level.

In this case the application protocol is http. If you received the header by having received `\r\n\r\n` (as it looks like), it might tell you how much data there is to be expected via this line:

```
Content-Length: 0
```

It in fact here it tells you there is `0` bytes to come for this request.

Comment: A `Content-Length` header is not the only possibility, see [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4).